# Ballroom e Youkoso Episode 14 & 19 OST question?

Tags: music, merchandise, welcome-to-the-ballroom

I have the OST Soundtrack for Ballroom e Youkoso, but can't find this song.

The OST starts at roughly 7:20 for ep 14 when Chinatsu and Akira are arguing,

and at roughly 12:00 for ep 19 when Akira has the guy apologize. I would really appreciate if someone could find me this song.

Here is a fan-made cover of the song for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXBjv-6pcIo

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this for a while, looked through the OST, Disc 1,2: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pGAUF9cJTY)
 The soundtrack was [released on the sixth of December 2017](http://www.shi-no-kakaku.com/2017/12/ballroom-e-youkoso-original-soundtrack.html).

BallroomEYoukoso subreddit user "BeKley", [said:](https://www.reddit.com/r/BallroomEYoukoso/comments/79zghn/which_song_is_from_episode_13/)

> "It’s part of the Ballroom e Youkoso OST which hasn’t been released yet unfortunately.
>   However, someone has made really accurate covers of these OSTs and they’ve also done the song you’ve been looking for: https://youtu.be/rXBjv-6pcIo"

I've come to the same conclusion as him, another user in the post "ImDasman" also agreed.
This was 5 months ago, it may have been released since but I doubt it.